# Where's the accounts tab disappeared to?

Tags: support, profile-page

There used to be a separate accounts tab on the user profile page - I see that the accounts tab that was around is no longer seen - where's it gone to?

Any reason it was removed? That tab was a quickfire way of figuring out how active a user is over the network and to follow the user's trail(to check for cross posts, spam etc)

Comment: It's been replaced by the accounts listing on the global SE profile. The real question is **why** it was removed. I probably used that more than most anything else on the user profile.

Comment: @TheEstablishment Yes, added that to question

Comment: Mainly it was useful for moving from one account to another easily. Why it's removed?

Comment: @TheE I don't see much of a difference.. Before, you had to `Profile->Accounts tab`. Now, you have to `Profile->Accounts snippet(in summary)`. Same number of clicks, just two scroll-ticks down. :/

Comment: @Man: A *lot* more scrolling. Also, my muscle memory is now rendered worthless. I liked my cheese just where it was, thankyouverymuch.

Comment: May be it's done for increasing SE's trafiic.

Comment: @TheEstablishment: Hmm, it wouldn't be much work to program a userscript that puts a link to the SE global accountlist in the same place as the original thingy. Yay jQuery! `$("<a href='http://stackexchange.com/users/1212053/manishearth?tab=accounts'>Accounts</a>").insertAfter($("#tabs a:last"))`

Comment: @TheEstablishment: Replace the SE global link with yours in the above script. Also, I can't remember where the accounts tab used to be--so if you want, I can move it..

Comment: @TheEstablishment: See my answer below--userscript created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The profile page still shows the user's top accounts.
In the profile page, scroll down until you see a section heading named `Accounts`.
It's not obvious but this heading is also linked to the complete account list in the network profile.

([Source and hat tip](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128940/136036))

Answer (score 4):

For those of you who really want the button back, here's a jquery:

`$("<a href='"+$('.user-panel-footer a[alt="full list of accounts"]')[0].href+"'>Accounts</‌​a>").insertAfter($("#tabs a:last"))`

Let me know if its in the wrong position...

UPDATE: [Userscript!!!](https://stackapps.com/questions/3303/bring-back-the-accounts-tab)

Comment: I don't have a place to host this, but someone could convert this to a userscript, I guess.

Comment: How to run that on client side?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk: For that, I'd need to userscript it..

Comment: @SomnathMuluk: I have a userscript, I'll upload it to git or something

Comment: @SomnathMuluk: See userscript (link in question)

Comment: Will you please give how to use that code?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk: See the userscript link.. You have to be using Chrome (Or firefox with greasemonkey)

Comment: @SomnathMuluk [How do I install a userscript?](http://superuser.com/q/252046/4377)

Comment: @Sathya: */me loves it when other people do the work of digging up links.* Thanks!

Comment: Pleasure, thanks for the userscript!

Comment: @Sathya note that the script is hastily-cobbled by me(im not that good at jquery/userscripts). Let me know if there are any bugs/improvements! :)

Answer (score 1):

Q1: Where is gone to?

Anybody who don't know how to go to accounts tab now:

1. Go to your Network profile. [image: Network profile]
2. Then got to accounts tab same as which was present previously in each accounts tab.[image: accounts tab]

Q2: Any reason it was removed?

I would say they have increased more number of clicks. Which was easily available 1stly.

(Now for any purpose we have to go to SE. They might have done this to increase SE's traffic.)

I will not able to give right answer about 2nd question. Officials/ moderators might give correct reason for the same.

Comment: I guess a reason it was moved was that it logically belongs on the global SE profile rather than on each site. But it is still on th profile pages represented as a section in the Summary tab, as noted in [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128940/135505) to a dupe on your question.

Comment: It's shown in summary section with top 5 accounts for easy traversal(Less clicks). But if want to see other accounts you have to traverse it through your network(SE) profile.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The quickest shortcut from there to the full list is to click on the header of that Accounts header or below the list in the same section where it say "View more" (with an icon of the SE site to indicate that it is located there).