# Where did the user profile's "Accounts" tab go?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where's the accounts tab disappeared to?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128368/wheres-the-accounts-tab-disappeared-to)

Either I'm growing old and my mind is slipping, or **the `Accounts` tab was removed from the user profile page.** I didn't find a mention of this in [the MSO post about "recent changes"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange). Am I mistaken?

That's a pity, because I imagine that it used to be convenient to look up a new site user and use that tab to check whether he's already familiar with the concept of the SE network; if no other accounts were listed he's a noob, and if lots of other high-rep accounts were listed he's a veteran -- and I can **adjust my answers or my moderator actions accordingly.**

Now, to find out whether a user has other SE accounts, I need to:

1. first go to his site account page,
2. and from there to his network profile,
3. and then to the accounts tab.

It would be much easier to see a small summary of the user's other network accounts in the user's site profile. Why not?

Comment: The "accounts" section in the profile page links directly to the accounts tab in the network profile - same number of clicks as before AFAICT.

Comment: You're mistaken, click the "Accounts" header on the profile main page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A user's accounts are still listed on their profile, next to their badges:

[image]

All you need to do is scroll down a bit when checking a user's profile.

Comment: Thank you, this is correct! I didn't see this section; there are so many. I was looking at the tabs in the profile page.

Comment: **@TorbenGundtofte-Bruun** You are not alone. I didn't see it either.